# Make Intellij IDEA allow lambda in java 5 6 7 language level with IDE support

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

Because of [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda), 
we can use java 8 lambda feature in java 5 6 7. so, 
How to make Intellij Idea allow lambda in java 5 6 7 language level, also with ide features for lambda ?

Comment: Read the text from the link you yourself provided: "Use JDK 8 to compile your source code.". It says in pretty clear form that you need Java 8 language level to compile the code before running retrolambda over the compiled classes.

Comment: So, the question may like 'Disable Java8 API from Intellij' or 'Warning Java8 API usage'. In eclipse this is possible, but in intellij, is this possible ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA you will need to set the language level for the module to be Java 8, or else IDEA will give red squiggly lines about lambda expressions.

In `Settings | Inspections | Java language level migration aids | Usages of API documented as @since 1.5 (1.6|1.7)` you can choose it to warn about usages of API that is documented as `@since 1.8`.

Additionally you should run all the tests for your project using the Java 7 runtime, or whatever is your target. For Maven this can be configured using [Surefire's jvm property](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#jvm). During development, inside IDEA, it's more practical to run the tests just with Java 8.