# How to correctly user Path in FIO

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have some strange problem.
Going through the basic IO tutorial (from Oracle java SE tutorial) I got some problem: my Intellij editor shows red mark on the Path variable.
By default there was set 6 version of java, but I changed it on 8 and got nothing.
Where is the problem? (with path declaration of with my settings or something else?)

`Path path1 = Paths.get("D:\\folder1");`

here is rebuild log:

```
Information:javac 1.8.0_73 was used to compile java sources
Information:21.06.2017 14:48 - Compilation completed successfully with 3 warnings in 3s 704ms
Warning:java: source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
Warning:java: target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
Warning:java: To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
```

here is the error message of ide:

```
usage of API documented as @since 1.6+
```

i've rewrite it by hand coz suddenly can't copy it.

class code:

```
 import java.nio.file.*;


public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path1 = Paths.get("D:\\folder1");
    }
}
```

Project settings window:

[image]

---

I've got it:  Project Structure -> Modules ->Sources -> Language Level is help me

---

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: did you rebuild?

Comment: Have you included import statement `java.nio.file.Path`?

Comment: Import below 2 package.. `import java.nio.file.Path;` and
`import java.nio.file.Paths;`

Comment: add all in the body of the post

Comment: What kind of project is it? Is it a Maven, Gradle, IntelliJ, ... project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38576549/104891