# Truncate double numbers to two decimal places using DecimalFormat: Usage of API documented as @since 1.6+ error

Tags: java

I'm trying to use this code **to get number `2.90` printed from the intial number `2.90689`:**

```
double number = 2.90689;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);  //error
System.out.println(df.format(number));
```

However I get the `Usage of API documented as @since 1.6+ error` when trying to set rounding mode. How do I solve this in a modern way? All answers I've found use this seemingly deprecated code.

PS: It's not an error, but a warning in IDE. When run, it also doesn't work properly: prints `2.9` instead of `2.90`. I've made this repl: https://repl.it/repls/IllInterestingComputers.

Screenshot of the warning:
[image]

Comment: Is it an error or a warning?

Comment: @Jens a wwarning

Comment: And way you want fix it?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551978/usage-of-api-documented-as-since1-6/40732834

Comment: But it has been marked @since for a reason? Is there no non-deprecated way to truncate doubles?

Comment: It is marked so you know that is not available in Java 1.5 or less. It is not marked as deprected, which you should solve

Comment: do you want 2.90689 to be displayed as 2.90?

Comment: @dassum yes that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double number = 2.90689;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);  //error
System.out.println(df.format(number));
```

Please check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

```
0   Number  Yes Digit
#   Number  Yes Digit, zero shows as absent
```

Comment: So I should just - ignore the warning?

Comment: I didn't even get the warning in IntelliJ java 8.

Comment: The question is how to suppress the warning.Why you answer with code that shows the same warning/information?

Comment: @Jens No, it also turned out the code I had didn't print `2.90`, but rather `2.9` (see PS).

Comment: I asked @parsecer do you want 2.90689 to be displayed as 2.90? and he replied yes to it . So i posted the answer

Comment: @dassum I attached a screenshot of the warning

Comment: @dassum Turned out I asked language level 5 after all. I thought it was 8, because it was 8 for the project, but not the module (in Idea Intellij)

Comment: @parsecer that it is a different question as the first one and should asked as a new question

Answer (score 0):

[You should use BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal), heres an example:

```
double number = 2.90689;
BigDecimal roundedDown = BigDecimal.valueOf(number).setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println("Original: " + number);
System.out.println("Rounded: " + roundedDown);
```

Stdout:

```
Original: 2.90689
Rounded: 2.90
```

Comment: Why OP *should  use* BigDecimal. The number is not to big for a double

Comment: @Jens Loss of precision, added link to answer